# How to group photos using face api

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am using face API to group similar images. I was using face group where I am sending faceids and then getting groups as result. but as mentioned in https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395238 faceid is only for 24 hours and expire after that.But persistedFaceIds never get expire.Can you suggest how can i use persisted face ids to group images. Following is my requirement: I storing images on server. If I got new image I need to get face id and group accordingly. Whether I have to call api every time when I add an image to the server. please suggest how can I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Face Group is a very expensive/unefficient operation, you may try FindSimilar [1] or Identify to help in your scenario.

- [1] https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395237
- [2] https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395239